# Are there any (other-than-obvious) drawbacks to forward-declaring all classes in one header for a library?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Say there is a large project, with many classes. Adding and removing forward declarations in each separate header is tedious, but necessary because including every header slows compilation significantly.

Is it then a good idea to keep a list of all classes in one library in a special forward declaration list header, and include that in each class header file?
The obvious drawbacks I know of are:

- confusing compiler errors (mostly on MSVC) when one forgets to include a class header in another class's implementation.
- marginal increase in compile time due to a possibly long list of forward declarations
- maintenance of this list when classes are added/removed/renamed.

The last one should be an improvement over the case where forward declarations in each and every individual class header needs to be meticulously maintained.
An example of this system is e.g. the [`<iosfwd>` Standard Library header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd).

Are there any other drawbacks to such a system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of declarations will have to be modified whenever class is added/removed/renamed. The modification will cause nearly the entire project to be rebuilt instead of just the translation units that depend on the changed class name (because all headers and through inclusion, all translation units include it [except the ones that don't depend on any class, which I expect to be rare]). For big projects, this can mean an increase of incremental build time from a minute to several hours. That's hardly marginal.

A collection of forward declarations of **some** classes that are **stable**, that is included only by files that depend on the same (or at least similar) set of forward declarations might be useful.